# Need proper looking e-mail notification from Jenkins: including SVN changes made since last build and errors during buil, if any

Tags: jenkins, email-ext

Jenkins is used to poll SCM (SVN) using SVN plugin, then build using Ant/Maven/Gradle

In Post Build Actions, I`ve chosen Editable Email Notification, and under section of Triggers chose Always

And in Content section I have set the following tags (as is):

```
$PROJECT_DEFAULT_CONTENT

$CAUSE

$BUILD_LOG_REGEX

$CHANGES
```

Unfortunately it does not do what I want. First two is fine, but last two, I need them to send errors and warnings (only, not all the log), and what changes and in what particular files were made since last build.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, no one answered, but I find solution for changes on my own:

${CHANGES, showPaths=true, format="%a: %r %p \n--\"%m\"", pathFormat="\n\t- %p"}

As for $BUILD_LOG_REGEX, now when I know format, I`ll find solution too some time later.